# Uncaught ReferenceError: displayData is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to submit my form using AJAX. But its showing error `Uncaught ReferenceError: displayData is not defined` in the Console.

Moreover I want to Show the submitted data on the same blade when the Form is submitted. for which I've added Jquery in the blade which is also not working properly. Is there any way to save data using AJAX call and show the submitted data in the same blade when the Form is Submitted. And show the 2nd form which is also on this blade. As I've used smartWizard to save data from diffterent Forms.

Here is the `Blade`.

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    #display{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
    <div class="main-content-wrap sidenav-open d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="col-md-12 " id="display">
            <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent"> 
                    <div id="print-area">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Order Info</h4>
                                <p id="orderNoDis">{{ $sale->orderNo }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mt-3 mb-4 border-top"></div>
                        <div class="row mb-5">
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                <h5 class="font-weight-bold">Bill From</h5>
                                <p id="billFromDis">{{ $sale->billFrom }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-sm-right">
                                <h5 id="billToDis" class="font-weight-bold">Bill To</h5>
                                <p>{{ $sale->billTo }}</p>
                                <span id="billToAddressDis" style="white-space: pre-line">
                                    {{ $sale->billToAddress }}
                                </span>
                                <span id="billToPhoneDis" style="white-space: pre-line">
                                    {{ $sale->billToPhone }}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- SmartWizard html -->
        <div id="smartwizard">

            <div>
                <div id="step-1" class="">
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    @if(session()->has('message'))
                        <p class="alert alert-danger">{{ session('message') }}</p>
                    @endif
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active">
                        <!--==== Edit Area =====-->

                        <form action="{{ route('sale.store') }}" method="post" id="formToSubmit">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="row mb-5">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <h5 class="font-weight-bold">Bill From</h5>
                                    <div class="col-md-10 form-group mb-3 pl-0">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bill_from" id="bill_from" placeholder="Bill From" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                                    <h5 class="font-weight-bold">Bill To</h5>
                                    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2 form-group mb-3 pr-0">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" name="bill_to" id="bill_to" placeholder="Bill From" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2 form-group mb-3 pr-0">
                                        <textarea class="form-control text-right" name="bill_to_address" id="bill_to_address" placeholder="Bill From Address" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2 form-group mb-3 pr-0">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-right" name="bill_to_phone" id="bill_to_phone" placeholder="Bill From Phone No" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2 form-group mb-3 pr-0">
                                        <a  class="btn btn-primary" id="dataShow" onclick="displayData()">Save</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>    
                        <!--==== / Edit Area =====-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#formToSubmit').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

            function displayData()
            {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
                    }
                });
                var bill_from_val = $('#bill_from').val();
                var bill_to_val = $('#bill_to').val();
                var bill_to_address_val = $('#bill_to_address').val();
                var bill_to_phone_val = $('#bill_to_phone').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8000/sale/store', // URL
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { // here we are sending data to next request
                        _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                        billFrom: bill_from_val,
                        billTo: bill_to_val,
                        billToAddress: bill_to_address_val,
                        billToPhone: bill_to_phone_val,
                        // user_id: user_id
                    },
                    dataType:'JSON',
                    success: function (result){
                        if( result.success == 'true ')
                        {
                            var data = result.data;
                            $('#billFromDis').text(data.billFrom);
                            $('#billToDis').text(data.billTo);
                            $('#billToAddressDis').text(data.billToAddress);
                            $('#billToPhoneDis').text(data.billToPhone);
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#dataShow").click(function(){
            $("div").removeClass("display");
          });
        });
    </script>
@stop
```

Here is the Controller Code.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'order_no' => 'unique:sales,orderNo',
            'bill_from' => 'required|min:3',
            'bill_to' => 'required|min:3',
            'bill_to_address' => 'required',
            'bill_to_phone' => 'required|min:11'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            if($request->ajax())
            {
                return response()->json(array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'There are incorect values in the form!',
                    'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
                ), 422);
            }
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

            $sale = new Sale();
            $sale['orderNo'] = mt_rand();
            $sale['billFrom'] = $request->bill_from;
            $sale['billTo'] = $request->bill_to;
            $sale['billToAddress'] = $request->bill_to_address;
            $sale['billToPhone'] = $request->bill_to_phone;
            $sale->save();
            //return redirect()->route('saleCreate2');

            $request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
            json_encode(array('success' => 'true', 'data' => $sale));
```

Tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Looks like your script is loaded before the DOM. try moving your `<script>` at the end of the page, or use `$( document ).ready()` or `<script defer>`

Comment: you have a typo in line three of your controller code. Guess it is just for copy/paste?

Comment: That happened unconsciously.

Answer (score 0):

Better you put an id in the form and then you put your ajax code inside the submit function. For example below:

```
<form id="formToSubmit">
</form>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#formToSubmit').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // To prevent reloading the page or redirecting the page
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
                }
            });
            var bill_from_val = $('#bill_from').val();
            var bill_to_val = $('#bill_to').val();
            var bill_to_address_val = $('#bill_to_address').val();
            var bill_to_phone_val = $('#bill_to_phone').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/sale/store', // URL
                type: 'POST',
                data: { // here we are sending data to next request
                    _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                    billFrom: bill_from_val,
                    billTo: bill_to_val,
                    billToAddress: bill_to_address_val,
                    billToPhone: bill_to_phone_val,
                    // user_id: user_id
                },
                dataType:'JSON',
                success: function (result){
                    if( result.success == 'true ')
                    {
                        var data = result.data;
                        $('#billFromDis').text(data.billFrom);
                        $('#billToDis').text(data.billTo);
                        $('#billToAddressDis').text(data.billToAddress);
                        $('#billToPhoneDis').text(data.billToPhone);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: @nomie may I see your whole blade and js file

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: displayData is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM2201 create:498)`

Comment: @nomie remove the onlick function in input tag. It should be this `<a  class="btn btn-primary" id="dataShow" type="submit">Save</a>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195521/discussion-between-joefrey-r-ramos-and-nomie).